# Need help to find bug in code with textures in Open GL ES 2.0 using shaders

Tags: opengl-es, shader, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Ive been using Open GL ES 2.0 Programming guide and am following chapter 9 about textures but ive set up the same pixel array (2x2- Red Green Blue Yellow) and it only shows red for the whole triangle. Cant seem to find the problem, i think my shaders are fine too please help my code follows.

```
- (void)setupGL
   {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gRectVertexData), gRectVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// 2 x 2 Image, 3 bytes per pixel(R, G, B) 
GLubyte pixels[12] =
{
    255,0,0, // Red 
    0,255,0, // Green
    0,0,255, // Blue
    0,255,255 // Yellow 
};
    // Use tightly packed data
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Generate a texture object 
glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    // Bind the texture object 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    // Load the texture
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, 2,2, 0, GL_RGB,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
// Set the filtering mode
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    GLint SamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "Texture");
glUniform1i(SamplerLoc, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

}

I have this in my load shaders part

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_NORMAL, "normal");
glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_TEX, "TexCoordIn");
```

then my vertex shader and fragment shader are as follows

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
  vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
  vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.8, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

  float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

  colorVarying = diffuseColor*nDotVP;

  gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
  TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

The Fragment Shader

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main()
{
lowp vec4 col = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
col.x *= colorVarying.x;
col.y *= colorVarying.x;
col.z *= colorVarying.x;
col.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor =  col;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your call

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_TEX, "TexCoordIn");
```

to use the `GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0` instead of your `ATTRIB_TEX` enum.

This is an annoying gotcha in the OpenGL Game project.  The enum members they use in their `glBindAttribLocation` calls for positions and normals happen to have the same values as the GLKVertexAttribPosition and GLKVertexAttribNormal enums, but this is just a coincidence.

Check out the post at [headnoodles](http://www.headnoodles.com/2012/02/using-textures-in-xcode-4-opengl-es-1.html) for step by step instructions.  The example uses GLKit but everything else should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just output your texture coordinates?

Do you see the gradient from [0-1]?

Comment: i used gl_FragColor =  vec4(TexCoordOut.x,TexCoordOut.y,1,1); and got just blue so i can see its something wrong with texture coordinates so can you see where i have gone wrong. have i put the attributes correctly for declaring vertices

Comment: does your model/mesh has correct uv coordinates? If yes the input texture coordinates are wrong. Then I cannot help you because I don't know OpenGl well, I just programmed a lot of Shaders but did not worked at the OpenGl/DirectX Level. But at least you could narrow down the error. Its always a good start to develop or port your shader to Rendermonkey so that you are sure that the Shader and meshes are at least correct.